# How to drag and drop an image between two images using DragTargetPanel on Vaadin 14

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14

I need to be able to drag and drop an image between two images using a DropTargetPanel on Vaadin. Currently, it's only possible to move the image to the end, but not between two images. If I need to keep the image between two images, in this case, I need more steps to do that.

For a Grid component, for example, there is a method called "setDropMode" where is possible to set as "GridDropMode.BETWEEN". In this case, is possible to drag and drop a row between two rows. I would like to do the same for my images through DropTargetPanel.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: If you have already code with your attempts or an MVE, please add it.

Comment: In the layout you can add component at index using `addComponentAtIndex(index, component)` method. That is probably what you are looking for. So you need to check the index of the target component and then add it using that.